# How to use coffeescript with Sinatra

Tags: sinatra, coffeescript

I'm trying to get coffeescript working with Sinatra. I'm new to both technologies so this is probably something silly. My problem seems to be that the coffeescript compiles to javascript but doesn't execute on page, instead appearing as html.

```
#sinatra app
require 'coffee-script'
get "/test.js" do
  coffee :hello
end

#hello.coffee
alert "hello world"

#My page (/test.js) doesn't execute the js - just displays the code

#On screen in the browser I get this:
   (function() {
  alert("hello world");
}).call(this);

#In the HTML I get this within the body tags

<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">(function() {
  alert('hello world!');
}).call(this);
</pre>
```

Comment: When you say "In the HTML," what HTML are you referring to? How did your JavaScript get embedded in there? Also, there's an inconsistency above—`"hello world"` vs. `"hello kids"`.

Comment: When I say "in the HTML" I mean when I view the source of the page. Inconsistency fixed - sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Right, I understand that, but I'm asking: How did you create that page on Sinatra's end?

Answer (score 6):

Hmm... it looks like your example is based on [this Sinatra documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#CoffeeScript%20Templates). But for some reason, Sinatra is trying to serve the `.js` file as HTML, and is preprocessing it accordingly. Are you by any chance setting `content_type` elsewhere in your application? Try changing your code to

```
get "/test.js" do
  content_type "text/javascript"
  coffee :hello
end
```

You could also try a completely different approach, using either [Rack::Coffee](https://github.com/mattly/rack-coffee) or [Barista](https://github.com/Sutto/barista) to compile your CoffeeScript to JavaScript automatically at the Rack level. That might be easier if you have a large number of CoffeeScript files anyway.

**Edit:** After posting the above, it struck me that I'm probably just misinterpreting your markup. Is what you see when you load the page `test.js` in your browser just

```
alert('hello world!');
```

? If so, everything is working fine. JavaScript is only going to run in your browser when it's in an HTML page between `<script>` tags, or referenced via `<script src="test.js"></script>`. So in addition to your existing code, add

```
get "/alert", :provides => 'html' do
  '<script type=src="test.js"></script>'
end
```

then open that `alert` address in your browser, and the script should run.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I tried both but still no luck - you are right about it not being in the script tags though. I added extra information in the question about what I'm seeing. Might try the rack level solutions.

Answer (score 3):

From [sinatra-coffee-script-template](https://github.com/zacharyscott/sinatra-coffee-script-template)
I was just looking for the same setup.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'
require 'coffee-script'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

get '/application.js' do
  coffee :application
end
```

then in application.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('button:first').click ->
    $('body').toggleClass 'dark', 'light'
```

index.erb

```
<h1>I'm living the dream</h1>
<button>Click me</button>
```

layout.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Sinatra Coffee-Script Template</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .dark {
      background: #2F2F2F;
      color: #7F7F7F;
    }
    .light {
      background: #EEEEEE;
      color: #2F2F2F;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/listeners.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you didn't mention about application.js in the index.erb or in layout.erb..how is sinatra would throw it to the browser

Answer (score 2):

I usually just setup a watcher on my CoffeeScript files while developing `coffee -wc dirname/` and then deploy the compiled JS files to production. It's not ideal, but it's less complicated in some ways and removes the dependency on Node.JS from my production server (which in my case is Heroku.)

Comment: Actually, Ruby's `coffee-script` gem (now a default in Rails 3.1) doesn't depend on Node. It runs CoffeeScript's compiler (which is a JavaScript file) via [ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs), which in turn will look for the [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) gem; that's a JavaScript interpreter with no dependencies. Totally Heroku-friendly.

Comment: In particular, you want [therubyracer-heroku](https://github.com/aler/therubyracer-heroku).

Comment: yeah that gem comes in handy. hadn't heard how it worked before but it makes perfect sense now (precompile coffeescript to javascript with a ruby based javascript interpreter)

Comment: Or, if you're using JRuby, [therubyrhino](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyrhino).

Answer (score 0):

Use a gem like sinatra-asset-snack (https://rubygems.org/gems/sinatra-asset-snack) or even better, use a bootstrap to start your project so you don't have to worry about setting up all the plumbing (https://github.com/benkitzelman/sinatra-backbone-bootstrap)